# How to replace a TeamCity tag

Tags: teamcity

I am trying to replace a tag that was added to a build with a new one on a new build.

I can create the tag using the following command:

`curl -v -H "Content-Type:text/plain" -d "latest" https://<teamcity-server>/guestAuth/app/rest/builds/id:49346/tags`

However when I run another build, the next build creates another latest tag and it thus sohwing two latest tags instead of moving the latest tag to the new build. Looking at TeamCity documentation is not help much.  How can delete the older tags without manually deleting them in UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround you can use REST API. Get build which need to replace/delete the tag. use the request:

```
https://<teamcity-server>/guestAuth/app/rest/builds/id:49346/tags?locator=tags:<tag_name>
```

Delete/replace needed tag in returned XML and use [PUT request](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildTags) to replace tags.